# SQL: produce aggregate results table for the last 12 months, excluding the current month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, I've written some code to produce an aggregate results table that calculates the average wait time (from referral to appointment date) for all appointments within the month.

Based on whatever day the query is run, I want it to produce me a table of results for the previous 12 **full** months, excluding the current month. So for example, if I run the query today (6th Sept 2017), I want the table of results to give me 12 rows for the months August 2017 back to Sept 2016, like this:

```
YEAR | MONTH | MONTHNAME | AVG DAYS WAIT
-----+-------+-----------+---------------
2017 |   8   |  August   |     42
2017 |   7   |   July    |     43
2017 |   6   |   June    |     47
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2016 |   9   | September |     42
```

I'm using the following code which does indeed return me a 12 month list and excludes the current month:

```
SELECT 
     year (OP.Appointment_Date) [Year]
    ,month (OP.Appointment_Date) [Month]
    ,DATENAME (month,OP.Appointment_Date) [MonthName]
    ,AVG(DATEDIFF (dd,OP.Received_Date,Appointment_Date)) [Avg Days Wait]

FROM 
    [HDM_Local].[Outpatients].[vw_OP_Appointments] OP WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE 
    OP.Appointment_Date >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
    AND OP.Appointment_Date < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())

GROUP BY 
     year(OP.Appointment_Date)
    ,month(OP.Appointment_Date)
    ,DATENAME(month,OP.Appointment_Date)

ORDER BY 
     year(OP.Appointment_Date)desc
    ,month(OP.Appointment_Date)desc
```

**However**, the problem I've found is that the result for the most recent month (August) is incorrect.

I know from validating my data that the average wait time in August was 42 days. The query above is actually giving me a figure of 50.

I'm presuming that what's happening is the `AND OP.Appointment_Date < DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())` statement is taking today's date, subtracting a full month's worth of days from it, and then calculating the average wait time for appointments in August based only on those appointments dated between 1st-6th August (or something along these lines).

The same issue also appears to be influencing the result for the oldest month in the list, I presume again because it's ignoring the first 5/6 days during Sept 2016 when performing the calculation.

Please can anyone explain how to code the statement to effectively *"ignore the current month and return the previous 12 months, based on the full range of dates within each month"*?

Comment: U should check for last date of previous month and first date of 12 months before. Check my answer below.

Comment: @Ravi, thanks with your help. Similar to my earlier reply to SqlZim, I'm trying run this but killing it after 30+ minutes still running. I'll feedback when I get a result through.

Comment: Try to with some less amount of data first then we try to optimise the query.

Answer (score 0):

Your `where` clause is subtracting months, but is not truncating to the start of each month.

This will give you the range that starts from the first day of the month 12 months ago through the end of last month:

```
where op.Appointment_Date >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )-12, 0)
  and op.Appointment_Date <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

---

Here is a comparison of your date range, vs a truncated to month date range:

```
select 
    TruncatedToMonth = 'N'
  , fromdate = dateadd(month, -12, getdate())
  , thrudate = dateadd(month, -1, getdate())
union all 
select 
    TruncatedToMonth = 'Y'
  , fromdate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )-12, 0)
  , thrudate = dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() ), 0)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/RGJ79943

returns:

```
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| TruncatedToMonth |      fromdate       |      thrudate       |
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| N                | 2016-09-06 14:38:07 | 2017-08-06 14:38:07 |
| Y                | 2016-09-01 00:00:00 | 2017-09-01 00:00:00 |
+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: many thanks for your help @SqlZim. I'm just attempting to run the code to see the result. The original code took 5 mins to run, but I've had a couple of attempts running it with your suggestion and I've had to kill it whilst still running at +20 mins... I guess the views I've been given to use run slowly, and perhaps this code is a little resource heavy also. I'll update once I get a result.

Answer (score 0):

WHERE 
    OP.Appointment_Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0)
    AND OP.Appointment_Date < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

--or --

WHERE 
    OP.Appointment_Date between DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0)
    AND  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1)

Basically:
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0) --First day of previous month
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) --Last Day of previous month

Answer (score 0):

I would personally remove your logic from the where clause and place them into a variable since they do not rely on columns (will reduce your overhead either a negligible amount or substantial, depending on your database).

Try these variables in your where clause, should return beginning of September 2016 to end of August 2017

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-12, 0) -- Get start of month 13 months before current
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), -1) -- Get end of latest month before current

SELECT @MinDate, @MaxDate
```

EDIT:  Just re-reading your post.  The way that `DATEADD MONTH` works, is to literally add or subtract that number of months from the date i.e. if it is the 6th September 2017, take 12 months from that which returns the 6th September 2016.  You can always take clauses like that out of your WHERE clause and place them into a select to see the effect they're having i.e.:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()), DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
```

Returning

```
(No column name)              (No column name)
2016-09-06 18:45:07.857       2017-08-06 18:45:07.857
```